# How to create ClassificationRequest with structured data to send to TensorFlow Serving with gRPC

Tags: python, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I trained & exported the Iris Classifier from [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/premade_estimators). I exported it by adding the following to [premade_estimator.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/premade_estimator.py):

```
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(my_feature_columns)
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
classifier.export_saved_model("iris_export_base", serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

I'm able to get inferences using the REST API like so:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/foo:classify', 
                         json={"examples": [{"SepalLength": 2.3, 
                                             "SepalWidth": 3.4, 
                                             "PetalLength": 2.2, 
                                             "PetalWidth": 0.81}]})
```

I've also been able to successfully get inferences with other models using gRPC, like this object detection model which takes as input an image as an array:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(SERVER_ADDR)
stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = MODEL_SPEC_NAME
request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image_ary))
result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
```

But I can't figure out how I'm supposed to specify the inputs for a ClassificationRequest. My best guess is something along these lines:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(SERVER_ADDR)
stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
request = classification_pb2.ClassificationRequest()
request.model_spec.name = MODEL_SPEC_NAME
request.input #...?
```

But I can't find any information about how to set the input, and everything I've tried so far throws some kind of TypeError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of specifying the input here: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server_test.py#L354:

example = request.input.example_list.examples.add()
example.features.feature['x'].float_list.value.extend([2.0])